How can I design streaming assertions in Java 17?
Preface, I'm pretty sure what I'm doing here is wrong.
In a perfect world, I'd like a way to stream assertions on a result captor so that I can do something like:
@InjectMocks
MyOtherServiceThatInvokesMyService otherService;

@Mock
MyService myService;

// ...

@Test
void test() {
    List<String> expectedStrings = List.of("Hello", "world", "this", "is", "strangely", "difficult");

    // Need help designing this...
    MyResultCaptor<String> resultCaptor = new MyResultCaptor(
        expectedStrings, 
        Assertions::assertEquals
    );

    doAnswer(resultCaptor).when(myService).doesSomethingThatReturnsAString();

    // Let's pretend this will invoke myService 6 times, each in it's own thread
    // I want this to throw on the first unexpected result
    otherService.doTheThingThatStartsThreads();
}

My motivation is that I don't want to have to iterate over the results in the list of what's returned from the ResultCaptor's getValues and instead want it to throw the AssertionFailedException the first time it encounters a problem.
https://dev.to/ulrich/create-and-use-a-result-captor-in-mockito-1l9i
// slightly modified to capture all values
public static class ResultCaptor<T> implements Answer<T> {
    private List<T> values = null;
    private T lastValue = null;

    public T getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public List<T> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public T answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        //noinspection unchecked
        lastValue = (T) invocationOnMock.callRealMethod();
        values.add(lastValue);
        return result;
    }
}

Here's the idea...
public static class MyResultCaptor<T, R> extends ResultCaptor<T> {
    // stuff...

    public MyResultCaptor(List<T> expectedResults, BiConsumer assertion) {
       // set stuff
    }

    @Override
    public T answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        lastValue = (T) invocationOnMock.callRealMethod();
        values.add(lastValue);
        try {
            assertion.accept(lastValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

}

Does this make any sense at all? I've got it mostly working except for the threaded part. Since the assertion is happening in MyResultCaptor and it throws from there it's being caught inside of the newly opened thread and as such does not propagate up to the main thread - which is to be expected. I'm thinking I need to have some kind of callback patterns so that I can pass a callback into the thread invocation such that it can join back with the main thread so it can bubble up the exception but that doesn't seem right?
Any help would be appreciated, I think I just reached the limitations of my knowledge on threads at the moment.

You can inject the executor into the class you're testing, and use an executor that just runs tasks on the current Thread.

This is a simplified example as a goal for eventual integration testing. OtherService actually invokes many other services that may or may not have their own ExecutorService and I don't want to muck with that if possible.

I'm thinking about it like, if I mock the executor then I'm bypassing what kind of thread pool it uses in the real downstream threads.

If you are going to verify the result of a real method call, why not test "myService" directly instead of via a mock? In other words, I do not see a reason why you would need a "ResultCaptor" in the first place.
